# S3 lifecycle transition: Does LastModified date change after a transition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

Does object last modified date changes when we do transition object from standard to Glacier?

I checked on AWS docs but I didn't get any information on metadata change during Transitioning. When we do copy/move it will create new `LastModified` date. Does it create new `LastModified` during transitions?

Comment: Last modified date remains unchanged when lifecycle management transitions an object from one S3 storage class to another.

Comment: Thank you @zedfoxus . It means transtition happens based on creation date rather than last modified date ?

Comment: Creation date is one of the factors. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-actions gives you more information about what is used to do the math. The last modified date, though, remains unchanged.